# VB Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses

Tags: excel, vb.net, blueprism

I have the following code to insert a drop down list in Excel. Note I am calling this code via Blueprism.

```
GetInstance(handle).Activecell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,Formula1:=("Yes,No")
```

This is producing the following error

```
Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses
```

Comment: So did you add the parenthesis? `GetInstance(handle).Activecell.Validation.Add (Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,Formula1:=("Yes,No"))`

Comment: So I did try that, that is producing two more errors. Page: Input Validation List
Stage: Input Validation List
Type: Error
Action: Validate
Description: Compiler error at line 1: 'xlValidateList' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Page: Input Validation List
Stage: Input Validation List
Type: Error
Action: Validate
Description: Compiler error at line 1: 'xlValidAlertStop' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: You probably need to add some more code to your post.  Were are xlValidateList and xlValidAlertStop decleared?

Comment: So this is all the code. In Blueprism it operates a bit differently. I can try adding declarations but don't know the code for this? I thought they were usable functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial error was being caused by the lack of brackets. However, this prompted further errors around the Excel constants.

Final code:

```
GetInstance(handle).Activecell.Validation.Add (Type:=3, AlertStyle:=1,Formula1:=("Yes,No"))
```